# How to write Update API in Spring web flux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am pretty new to Spring web flux reactive programming. So this is little confusing.

I am writing update API with spring web flux. Passed request body tp the update method is a Mono of request. So My problem is How can I get the request body and perform with? . Please check the commented line in following code.

```
public Mono<User> updateUser(String userId, Mono<UserRequest> user){

    return userRepository.findById(userId)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("User not found")))
        .flatMap(foundUser -> {
            // How to get passed user object from Mono<UserRequest>
            modelMapper.map(source, foundUser);
            return Mono.just(userRepository.save(foundUser))
        })
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: While you might be new to Spring, you are not new to Stack Overflow. Don't misuse tags and read them before tagging. The mono tag is clear for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.zipWith(user, (foundUser, user) -> ...` (or simples `.zipWith(user)` that returns `Tuple`).

Samples:

```java
    @Test
    void x1() {
        Mono<String> m1 = Mono.just("S1");
        Mono<String> m2 = Mono.just("S2");

        m1
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("User not found")))
            .zipWith(m2, (s1, s2) -> s1.concat(s2)) // can be simplified to 'String::concat'
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .assertNext(s -> assertThat(s)
                .isEqualTo("S1S2")
            )
            .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    void x2() {
        Mono<String> m1 = Mono.just("S1");
        Mono<String> m2 = Mono.error(new RuntimeException("some-error"));

        m1
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("User not found")))
            .zipWith(m2, String::concat)
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectErrorSatisfies(throwable -> assertThat(throwable)
                .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
                .hasMessage("some-error")
            )
            .verify();
    }

    @Test
    void x3() {
        Mono<String> m1 = Mono.error(new RuntimeException("some-error"));
        Mono<String> m2 = Mono.just("S2");

        m1
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("User not found")))
            .zipWith(m2, String::concat)
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectErrorSatisfies(throwable -> assertThat(throwable)
                .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
                .hasMessage("some-error")
            )
            .verify();
    }

    @Test
    void x4() {
        Mono<String> m1 = Mono.empty();
        Mono<String> m2 = Mono.just("S2");

        m1
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("User not found")))
            .zipWith(m2, String::concat)
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectErrorSatisfies(throwable -> assertThat(throwable)
                .isInstanceOf(NotFoundException.class)
                .hasMessage("User not found")
            )
            .verify();
    }
```

Btw, there is a super-handy documentation from reactor: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator

I am also wondering why you pass `Mono<UserRequest> user` - where does it come from and why you cannot use plain `UserRequest user`?

Also, your repository is suspicious - why `findById` returns a reactive object, while `save` does not? It looks like a blocking call, hence you loose benefits of webflux/reactor.

Comment: Hi @asceta.
Thank you for the reply. why you pass Mono<UserRequest> user? Actually we are following api first approach with swagger. This is something auto genarated based on api.yml.

Answer (score 0):

> // How to get passed user object from Mono

Start with that Mono (the repository calls are non-reactive operations anyway):

```
public Mono<User> updateUser(String userId, Mono<UserRequest> user){
    return user.map(request -> ...);
}
```

Read: Once the UserRequest object is available, do ...